# How can I create vector of multiple strings containing specific column names?

Tags: r, string, vector, rename

Given a 3 x 100 matrix, how could I create a vector of strings containing individual column names? Specifically, columns comprise 20 sets of 5 consecutive measures and therefore strings should match variable (i.e. varA, ... varC), sets (SET1 to SET20) and order (1 to 5). For example:

```
my_matrix = replicate(100, rnorm(3)) 

my_names <- c("varA.SET1.1", "varA.SET1.2", "varA.SET1.3", "varA.SET1.4", "varA.SET1.5",
              "varA.SET2.1", "varA.SET2.2", "varA.SET2.3", "varA.SET2.4", "varA.SET2.5",

              ...

              "varC.SET5.5")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sprintf`.

```
v <- LETTERS[1:3]
set <- 1:20
ord <- 1:5

ex <- expand.grid(v, set, ord) 
my_names <- sprintf("var%s.SET%i.%i", ex[, 1],ex[, 2], ex[, 3])

head(my_names)
#[1] "varA.SET1.1" "varB.SET1.1" "varC.SET1.1" "varA.SET2.1" "varB.SET2.1"
#[6] "varC.SET2.1"
```

Comment: Or instead of specifying each column, `do.call(sprintf, c(fmt = "var%s.SET%i.%i", ex))`